# Will auto heal kill a web job in process?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We recently implemented Auto Heal on our Azure account. It restarts itself every once in a while, maybe once per day.

We also noticed that some of our long-running cron jobs (web jobs) were not finishing.

Would an Auto Heal restart also kill any running web jobs? Could that explain why the crons are sometimes failing to finish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main processes for an Azure web app. There is the w3wp.exe process, which runs the website itself. The second main process is the w3wp.exe scm process, which runs KUDU.

All webjobs run on the w3wp.exe scm process (KUDU). Auto heal only restarts the site w3wp.exe process meaning your web jobs should not be impacted by auto heal. The exception here is that if you web job is pulling data from the main site when the site is recycling, this could cause your web job to fail due to the site being offline for the recycle.

You can observe your site processes by navigating to (replace sitename with your web app name) https://sitename.scm.azurewebsites.net/ProcessExplorer/
One item that you should ensure for long running web jobs is that you have 'always on' enabled. You can turn this feature on in the 'Application settings' blade for your web app.

You can also refer the link [Proactive Auto Heal](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/08/17/proactive-auto-heal/) to know more about this feature.